# Form Verification works on 2 fields but not the 3rd field - whats breaking the validation check

Tags: javascript, sql, forms, validation

I have a what I believe is pretty straight forward check.
Registration form checks 3 fields to ensure they are not already taken
username - email & serial number

Username & email work perfect but when I try to add the Serial Number check, it never shows the validation message.

so first here is the code from the WORKING username validation:

```
<!--Javascript for check username availability-->
<script>
function checkUsernameAvailability() {
$("#loaderIcon").show();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "check_availability.php",
data:'username='+$("#username").val(),
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
$("#username-availability-status").html(data);
$("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
error:function (){
}
});
}
</script>
```

and here is the code that I inserted for a new check for Serial Numbers:

```
 <!--Javascript for check serial availability-->
 <script>
 function checkSerialAvailability() {
 $("#loaderIcon").show();
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: "check_availability.php",
 data:'serialNumber='+$("#serialNumber").val(),
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
 $("#serialNumber-availability-status").html(data);
 $("#loaderIcon").hide();
 },
 error:function (){
 }
 });
 }
 </script>
```

and here is the check_availability.php code:

```
 // Code for checking email availabilty
 if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {
 $email= $_POST["email"];
 $sql ="SELECT UserEmail FROM  userdata WHERE UserEmail=:email";
 $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
 $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query-> execute();
 $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 if($query -> rowCount() > 0)
 {
 echo "<span style='color:red'>Email-id already exists.</span>";
 } else{    
 echo "<span style='color:green'>Email-id available for Registration.</span>";
 }
 }

 // Code for checking email availabilty
 if(!empty($_POST["serialNumber"])) {
 $serial= $_POST["serialNumber"];
 $sql ="SELECT serialNumber FROM  userdata WHERE serialNumber=:userial";
 $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
 $query-> bindParam(':userial', $serial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query-> execute();
 $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 if($query -> rowCount() > 0)
 {
 echo "<span style='color:red'>Email-id already exists.</span>";
 } else{    
 echo "<span style='color:green'>Email-id available for Registration.</span>";
 }
 }
```

Again the Username check works perfect, but the serial number does not.
I have been at this for awhile now and I dont see where I'm missing a step?

Please help

[Example of Form Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6On2q.png)

Answer (score 0):

you may check for the error 
echo $query->error;
or you can check if your SQL phrase is proper.

```html
// Code for checking email availabilty
 if(!empty($_POST["serialNumber"])) {
 $serial= $_POST["serialNumber"];

echo "this is serail coming : " . $serial ; 

 $sql ="SELECT serialNumber FROM  userdata WHERE serialNumber=:userial";

echo($sql);

 $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
 $query-> bindParam(':userial', $serial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query-> execute();
 $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 echo $query->error;

 if($query -> rowCount() > 0)
 {
 echo "<span style='color:red'>Email-id already exists.</span>";
 } else{    
 echo "<span style='color:green'>Email-id available for Registration.</span>";
 }
 }
```

Comment: I tried adding the code you posted however it did not return any values upon entering a serial number

Comment: in your Javascript file you may check if serialNumber is ok.                   
   console.log(  $("#serialNumber").val()  ) ;

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
 function checkSerialAvailability() {
 $("#loaderIcon").show();
 
    
      let serialNumber= $("#serialNumber").val();



      var form_data = {
        serialNumber : serialNumber 
 

      };
      
      
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: "check_availability.php",
   data:form_data,
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
 $("#serialNumber-availability-status").html(data);
 $("#loaderIcon").hide();
 },
 error:function (){
 }
 });
 }
 </script>
```